# Encrypted video streaming

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, encoding, video-streaming

[image]

I made this picture that explains what I'm trying to achieve.

Brief summary: I want users to be able to upload an encrypted video that only those which have the password will be able to see as a stream.
The point of all this is for the server to not be able to decipher it.

What I managed to do at the moment is only the first part, encrypting the chunks and sending them :

```js
fileInput.addEventListener("change", async () => {
    const file = fileInput.files[0]
    const stream = file.stream()
    const reader = stream.getReader() 
    while(true) {
        const {value, done} = await reader.read()
        if(done) break
        handleChunk(value)
    }
    const out = {
        size: file.size,
        type: file.type,
        encryptedStream: encryptedStream
    }
})

function handleChunk(chunk) { // chunk: Uint8Array
    const parsedChunk = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(chunk)
    encryptedStream.push(CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(parsedChunk, "encryptionKey").toString())
}
```

I guess you can also do this with File.slice() but I did not test it.

At this point I feel like I've looked into every API related to files/streams both in Node and in vanilla js but I can't find a way to make this work, all I've managed is to make a `Readable` out of the `encryptedStream` array in the backend.

```js
const Readable = require("stream").Readable
let readable = new Readable()
encryptedStream.forEach(aesChunk => readable.push(aesChunk))
readable.push(null)
```

I have doubts on how to stream it back to another frontend and literally no idea on how to play the video after deciphering it.
From what I've looked online, it looks like it's not possible to stream a crypted file, only to download it.

Is this possible to do ?

Comment: Make sure your un-encrypted data is inside a (buffer) Array. **(1)** If you're waiting until all of video is fully downloaded and then un-encrypted, for that you can simply pass the array as **blob** to a `<video>` tag. **(2)** If it's a large file, then you'll have to use MediaSource Extensions (MSE). First unencrypt whatever chunk you have received then package it for MSE as required by whatever your video format is (eg: if MP4, in some Array you write a `MOOF` header then add the individual frame data as extracted each from the un-encrypted array before feeding to video player).

Comment: @VCOne I'm trying to encrypt a stream not a full video. Also the server won't be able to decipher it, only other clients. The idea is to encrypt the chunks on the uploader client, and send them to other clients from the server. The clients receiving the crypted chunks will decipher them and then feed them into a video player.